# Count number of columns above a date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with several columns and I would like to know the number of columns above the date 2016-12-31 . Here is an example:

| ID | Bill | Date 1 | Date 2 | Date 3 | Date 4 | Bill 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 6 | 2000-10-04 | 2000-11-05 | 1999-12-05 | 2001-05-04 | 8 |
| 6 | 8 | 2016-05-03 | 2017-08-09 | 2018-07-14 | 2015-09-12 | 17 |
| 12 | 14 | 2016-11-16 | 2017-05-04 | 2017-07-04 | 2018-07-04 | 35 |

And I would like to get this column

| Count |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

Comment: See if you require any further clarification from the answers below.  If no more question,  let us know any of the answers best fit for your needs by accepting the answer you choose.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create the mask and call `sum` on `axis=1`

```py
date = pd.to_datetime('2016-12-31')
(df[['Date 1','Date 2','Date 3','Date 4']]>date).sum(1)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
0    0
1    2
2    3
dtype: int64
```

If needed, call `.to_frame('count')` to create datarame with column as `count`

```py
(df[['Date 1','Date 2','Date 3','Date 4']]>date).sum(1).to_frame('Count')
   Count
0      0
1      2
2      3
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`df.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to filter the `Date*` columns + [`.sum(axis=1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html)

```
(df.filter(like='Date') > '2016-12-31').sum(axis=1).to_frame(name='Count')
```

Result:

```
   Count
0      0
1      2
2      3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
df['Count'] = (df.loc[:, [x for x in df.columns if 'Date' in x]] > '2016-12-31').sum(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
     ID   Bill      Date 1      Date 2      Date 3      Date 4   Bill 2  Count
0     4      6  2000-10-04  2000-11-05  1999-12-05  2001-05-04        8      0
1     6      8  2016-05-03  2017-08-09  2018-07-14  2015-09-12       17      2
2    12     14  2016-11-16  2017-05-04  2017-07-04  2018-07-04       35      3
```

We select columns with 'Date' in the name. It's better when we have lots of columns like these and don't want to put them one by one. Then we compare it with lookup date and sum 'True' values.